# jquery.form.js success function not working

Tags: http, jquery

I have form. I have made it submit asynchronously with jquery.form.js

The form submits successfully (I know because it updates a database every time) in current versions of IE and FF and Android Browser and Safari IOS.

The trouble I am having is with jquery.form.js .  The success function never triggers.  Even though the http request is successful.  I have verified that the request is successful using firefox network console.  I see http status code 200.
I am sending the request from www.myserver.com  to a php receiver file on subdomain.myserver.com

Here is the code:

```
 var options = {                         
                 beforeSubmit:  validate_form,  // pre-submit callback 
                 success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback  
                };
```

$('#form_0').ajaxForm(options);

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?  no errors in the JS console, status 200 in the network console.

as per request here is the showResponse function

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
{ 
     alert(responseText)
}
```

Comment: The code for ``showResponse`` would help

Comment: I have added the showResponse function, though it does not seem to matter.  Even if the function just says alert('foo');  the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
  });
```

Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Source:

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Is this solution going to be successful in cross-browser testing?

Comment: this is just an example all you have to do is replace success with done !!

Comment: I will give it a test tomorrow and let you know how it turns out.